# Change the default value of Custom Text box using plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I need to set default value for text box custom options based on some conditions. So that I used **after** plugin like below in di.xml of my module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text">
        <plugin name="set_default_custom_options_text" type="Company\Modulename\\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and Text.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Options\Type;
use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions;
Class Text {
    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(   
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function afterGetDefaultValue( \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text $subject, $result )
    {
        if( $this->getOption()->getTitle() == 'munit' )
            $result = 1;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In the above code if condition is not working, page just stop by displaying the option title.
Can you anyone help to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

check the bleow code

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Options\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions;
Class Text {
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $options
    public function __construct(   
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AbstractOptions $options
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->options = $options;
    }
    public function afterGetDefaultValue( \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text $subject, $result )
    {
        if( $this->options->getOption()->getTitle() == 'munit' )
            $result = 1;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I have changed little bit code modification. please compare your and my code to know the changes.

Comment: It's not working. Same problem is there still.

Comment: Here afterGetDefaultValue  you need to replace your custom attribute code  instead of DefaultValue.

Comment: $this->getOption() is not working.

Comment: use like this $this->options->getOption() instead of $this->getOption()

Comment: Not working for me. Is it working for you?

Comment: You need to get the $option from the $subject. $option = $subject->getOption(). Just like in @SIBHI S answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it work simply...my code is

```
namespace Company\Modulename\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Options\Type;

Class Text extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions {

    public function afterGetDefaultValue(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions $subject, $result)
    {

        if( $subject->getOption()->getTitle() == 'munit' )
            $result = 1;

    return $result;
    }
}
```

$subject object has all the properties and functions of the original **Text** class